# Data missing error when trying to echo created_at or updated_at

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an update user page in my webapp, and when I attempt to get information about a specific user, I get a data missing error as soon as I try to print out the created_at or updated_at columns. It works if I remove

```
<small>Oprettet: {{ date_format('%d%m%Y%h%m%s', $user->created_at) }} | Sist oppdatert: {{ date_format('%d%m%Y%h%m%s', $user->updated_at) }}</small>
```

Though as soon as I put it back in the error is back. I'm a little stuck here, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: take a look at the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps).

You might want to remove the `$this->timestamps` attribute or set it to

```
protected $timestamps = ['created_at', 'updated_at', ...];
```

with your own timestamps.

Hope this helps for you!

Comment: Seemed that I had to use the custom override for datetime in my eloquent model, thanks good sir.